# Part of speech of the word 'board' when in a compound word

Tags: parts-of-speech, compounds

When splitting the compound adjective 'onboard', there are two words; 'on' and 'board'.
'On' is a preposition, but what part of speech is 'board'?

Comment: Parts of words are not parts of speech. _On_ in _onboard_ is not a preposition, but a prefix.

Comment: The bases of compound words can be analysed by their word classes (parts of speech). For example, the compound adjective "threadbare", consists of noun+adjective. And the compound adjective "awe-inspiring" consists of noun+gerund-participle verb. Your example has the preposition "on" as its first base, but I'm just not sure whether "board" is a noun or a verb here.

Comment: @BillJ that is what I was wondering, whether 'board' is a noun or verb

Comment: I think "board" should be considered a noun. Other prep+noun compound adjectives include "**up.market** hotel" and "**in.flight** entertainment".

Comment: Thanks @BillJ I missed that! guess I read too quickly. Deleting the comment.